# Error during building of YAML_CPP with CMake on WIndows

Tags: cmake, mingw, yaml-cpp

I keep getting an error when I try to build yaml-cpp on Windows.
Using the CMake gui application I selected build- and sourcepath correctly, but as soon as I hit the "Configure" Button there is the following error thrown:

```
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "**MinGW Makefiles**".  **CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM** is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "MinGW Makefiles".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_C_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:C:/Users/Robert/Programs/Lib/yaml-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeCCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ENV_VAR
CMake Error: Error required internal CMake variable not set, cmake may be not be built correctly.
Missing variable is:
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file:C:/Users/Robert/Programs/Lib/yaml-cpp/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
CMake Error: CMAKE_C_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
CMake Error: CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER not set, after EnableLanguage
Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I know it has to do with the selected Generator, I selected **CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles**. However I have installed CodeBlocks correctly. So is there perhaps a way to set the **CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM** variable manually?

Comment: I think it is included in the CodeBlocks installation, isn't it?

Comment: Maybe, but i doubt that installer sets necessary env vars. Because of that CMake fails to locate MinGW toolchain.